# can not change dataGridView values from int to string in c#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to loop over a gridView after filling it from my database and change the values to a string depending on the previous value which is an integer but my program keeps breaking , the error I'm getting is in the pic

[image]

this is the code I've been trying

```
private void gridPrinting ()
    {     
        for (int i =0;i<dgvCus.Rows.Count;i++)
        {
            if (dgvCus.Rows[i].Cells["_type"].Value.ToString() == "1")
                dgvCus.Rows[i].Cells["_type"].Value = "زبون";
            else
                dgvCus.Rows[i].Cells["_type"].Value = "مورد";
        }       
    }
```

Comment: **You mean from string to int, right ?** Ok, first of all, It's dataGridView not a GridView, big difference here. Now for the main problem, you are trying to convert a string to int, but there is this value `hh` not valid as an integer, so you have to be sure that you have an integer, and the best thing to do here is to use [Int32.TryParse Method (String, Int32)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx) By the way : don't ignore the warnings , because you'll face another problems like NullReference

Answer (score 0):

Yes that's correct since your `Cells["_type"]` is of type `int` and you are trying to store a `string` to it and so the error. `"زبون"` not a number by any means